# React transform JSON array after .get call

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I have a React component which is creating an array from an AXIOS .get call and a resulting Object.keys().map function. Here is the initial JSON format:

```
"graph": {
  "tree": {
    "5bd356a0-b1ee-4e83-a7f8-8164a1a5ba09": {
      "5bd356a0-b1ee-4e83-a7f8-8164a1a5ba09": [
         "5bd356a7-d9cf-4043-865c-6a443729f665",
         "5bd356a7-b8da-4eb9-8174-2aeaa8659cb9",
         "5bd356a7-7148-44c9-ae02-570dced70346"                                                               
        ]       
 }
```

As you can see there is a nested array. Here is the .map function I am initially running:

```
const resultTree = Object.keys(fullTree).map(key => ({
          id: key,
          label: key,
          ...fullTree[key]
        }));
```

This is giving me an output of:

```
 {id: "5bd356a0-b1ee-4e83-a7f8-8164a1a5ba09", label: "5bd356a0-b1ee-4e83-a7f8-8164a1a5ba09", 5bd356a0-b1ee-4e83-a7f8-8164a1a5ba09: Array(67)}
```

What I want to do is get rid of the third appearance of the key (in this case "5bd356a0-b1ee-4e83-a7f8-8164a1a5ba09:" before the Array and also give the entire array a key of "ports".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help ?

```
const resultTree = Object.keys(fullTree).map(key => ({
  id: key,
  label: key,
  ports: fullTree[key][key]
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly this is one way of doing it:

```
const resultTree = Object.keys(fullTree).map(key => ({
          id: key,
          label: key,
          ports: fullTree[key][Object.keys(fullTree[key])[0]]
        }));
```

This assumes that the JSON structure is the same all the time. If you know that the key name is always identical on the two objects you can shorten it by just type `ports: fullTree[key][key]`

Comment: Thank you! I will try this!